# Nativescript-vue: how to move app.scss into a subfolder?

Tags: nativescript-vue

In a fresh initialized project (using `tns create --vue`), `app.scss` file is under root (`/app`) folder.

I'd like to move into /app/styles, but I cannot find what to change to tell nativescript to use this location instead of the default one.

**How to change default location of `/app/app.scss` to `/app/styles/app.scss` ?**

At this page ( https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/styling#application-wide-css ) I found these tip, but *is related to angular !*

> Application-wide CSS
>   When the application starts, NativeScript checks if the file app.css exists. If it does, any CSS styles that it contains are loaded and used across all application pages. This file is a convenient place to store styles that will be used on multiple pages.
>
> You can change the name of the file from which the application-wide CSS is loaded. You need to do the change before the application is started, usually in the app.js or app.ts file as shown below:
>
> `platformNativeScriptDynamic({ bootInExistingPage:false, cssFile:"style.css" });`
>
> The path to the CSS file is relative to the application root folder.

But I have no idea of where is this row of code. I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed just adding the following line at top of `app.js` file

```
import './styles/app.scss';
```